# navbar does not uncollapse when button is clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The menu does not uncollapse, when I click my button and I cant figure out why:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid"> 

<div class="navbar-header"> <!-- start of colllapsed navbar-->
  <button
    type="button"
    class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
    data-target="#main_navbar"
    aria-expanded="false"
  >open!</button>
</div> <!-- end of colllapsed navbar-->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar"> <!-- start of uncolllapsed navbar-->

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end of uncolllapsed navbar-->

    </nav>

    </div> <!-- end of container-->
```

Has it to do with the "id"? Or where have I made the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span id="open">Open!</span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3.0 Nav bar</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end of uncolllapsed navbar-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/k98Bn/14/)

Comment: Thanks alot! I changed the "navbar-inverse" back to "navbar-default" to make it white/light again. What does the <span> tag inside the <button> tag do?

Comment: @user2703522, the <span> tag acts like a placeholder. The above code will work even when the <span> tag is removed and "Open!" is specified within the <button> tag and also make sure button's id is set to "open" in order to change the font color to 'white'

Comment: Thx to you both. Nice to get some help and additional answers to the details.